# Compare Dates in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How can i compare Dates in Kotlin?
I have the Date of an Event as a String (Format:*dd/mm/yy*) and I want to check if it is within  the next 7 Days of the current Date.
The time in this case is not relevant or if needet I would use midnight.
Can someone please help me with this?

In my current code i got both Dates by this:

```
val date = document.data["Date"].toString()    //Example: 22/08/22 (dd/MM/yy)
val today = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy").format(Date()).toString()
```

this is within a Android environment.
I can't get the date more specific because i am getting it from a Database.

Comment: How would you compare two numbers? How would you check whether one number was within ±7 of another?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Parse string into `LocalDate` using its `parse` method. There’s no out-of-the-box `DateTimeFormatter` for `dd/mm/yy` format, but you can trivially create one using `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`.
2. Get current date using `LocalDate.now()`.
3. diff = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(now, date1)

Comment: i tryed it in a function like this:

`fun findDifference(end_date: String): Long {
        val localDate = LocalDate.parse(end_date)
        val today = LocalDate.now()
        val diff = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(today, localDate)

        return diff
    }`
with the input of "17/10/22",
but it keeps crashing my programm
Where do I have a mistake?

Comment: @Pantastix Read my instructions again, step 1 mentions a `DateTimeFormatter`. I could’ve easily given you the code, but I don’t encourage spoonfeeding, so, I provided clear instructions.

Comment: I just dont know where to use the DateTimeFormater to get it working

Comment: @Pantastix The Javadoc is your friend. Read it.